# Keep running Pi while charging batteries

Tags: power-supply, electronics, battery

I would like to build a simple automatic irrigation system with `Pi zero`, the thing is that I don't have access to electricity outside.
I thought to connect 5v solar panel + 3\4 chargeable batteries.

Im not that familiar with building control circuits for charging batteries, so my question is-

Lets say for the discussion its a sunny day,
if the batteries capacity is enough (above some threshold), the Pi will be powered by the batteries.

The issue is when I go under that threshold, how can I keep the Pi running as the batteries are being charged by the solar panel?

```
The load of the Pi is:

1. 6v water pump and transistor with resistor (connected to another non rechargeable batteries)
2. capacitive moisture sensor with mcp3002 ADC (I guess will be connected to the rechargeable batteries)
```

What circuit would you build to keep the Pi running?
Ill be very happy for explanation.

Thanks :)

Comment: You could ask the same question of any computer.  The Pi is not relevant to the question.

Comment: Just get a UPS for the Pi. I bought mine on Amazon and it's still working even after 7 months. You can plug a micro USB plug and you can charge and use it at the same time. It's also good for providing **5V** power to external devices.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do it: combine two (or more) batteries in a "wired-OR" configuration. This is fairly *generic* as you provided no details on your battery voltages. If you want to edit your question to add those details, we'll try to be more specific.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fJW1Wk.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>