# Is there any battery for Rpi that can be charged and used at the same time?

Tags: pi-3b+, battery

I'm making a security camera using Raspberry Pi 3B+ . I want suitable battery to power my rpi. Is there any suitable battery pack that can power Rpi at the same time recharge the battery? I also found lipo rider pro. Can this serve the purpose? Is there any other solution. My Rpi will also be connected to Wi-Fi.

Comment: you cannot charge and discharge a battery simultaneously ... electric current cannot flow in opposite directions through a wire ... you can power a device from a charger, with excess power being used to charge a battery,  basically power two devices using a charger

Comment: Google’power bank pass through’

Comment: Varta 57961 does this for me. Runs for 2 1/2 months now. But power supply to the  Varta is regularly off.

Answer (score 2):

The feature you want is called **pass-through charging** by some. It's not typically incorporated in "power banks" because [it's not good for the battery](http://community.anker.com/t/which-portable-chargers-support-pass-through-charging/31361).

You may wish to consider a commercial UPS [(examples)](https://www.walmart.com/browse/ups-battery-backups/c2hlbGZfaWQ6NDU2MDczOQieie) for this function. The battery is either charging (normal), or discharging if the AC power is disconnected.

Another commercial product that may accomplish this is a *dual redundant power supply* ([example])(https://www.jameco.com/Jameco/Products/ProdDS/2304391.pdf).

Still another way is to use a "wired-OR" power arrangement to supply power to your RPi. There were some answers posted recently that described how that works: [Answer 1](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/115894/83790), [Answer 2](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/111599/83790)

Answer (score 0):

JoyIt has a product called StromPi, which is basically an USV particularly designed for the Raspberry Pi: https://joy-it.net/de/products/rb-strompi3. It can be equipped with an optional battery so that it likely does what you need.

Downside is that it needs a bit of configuration to be really usable and "ordinary" PI housings cannot be used with it, because of the additional height.